# What are "free" and "fair" elections?

Tags: election

It's common to hear about "free and fair elections" (e.g. recently with Kenyan elections). In many elections there are international observers, which are suppose to judge whether elections were "free and fair". But **what is free and fair supposed to mean?**

For example, [this website](http://www.civicsacademy.co.za/video/free-and-fair-elections/) defines (emphasis mine):

> ‘Free’ means that all those **entitled** to vote have the right to be registered and to vote and must be free to make their choice.

But what if the law states that age of voting is 16, or 21? Or that there is a minimum income or education required to vote? Is **entitlement** necessarily idiosyncratic? Or is there an official guideline on this, e.g. by the UN?

Meanwhile, the same page defines (emphasis mine):

> ‘Fair’ means that all **registered** political parties have an equal right to contest the elections, campaign for voter support and hold meetings and rallies.

But what if the law states a "high" minimum requirement in terms of number of members for a political party to be recognised by the law? Who defines the "fair" conditions upon which groups can become legal political parties?

I have just selected some issues, but clearly there are more which are relevant to the discussion.

Comment: There are two problems with this question. First, it is far too broad. You admitted yourself that there are countless issues relevant to this discussion. Second, it is opinion-based. What's fair and what isn't is a completely subjective matter. Ask 10 people and you get 20 different answers. Which one is the "correct" answer? That depends solely on your personal value-system. To make this question on-topic, you could for example rephrase it to ask for how specific election monitoring organizations, like the ODIHR, define fair and free elections.